Why ChatInfo property is null in Get call Graph Communications API in a group call?
A peer-to-peer call between a Teams user A and Bot is escalated to a group call. Invite Participant API is used to invite a Teams user B. Now there are three participants, which confirms that this is a group call.
Expected output: Get Call API should give ChatInfo property with messageId, threadId, etc.
Actual Output: ChatInfo property is null.
Note: ChatInfo value was coming before 2 months.
Is there any change in this property from Graph API Team? I need this chat information of a group call to create Join URL, so that Teams Recording Bot can join the group call with help of join URL


The ChatInfo property is null in the Get call Graph Communications API for a group call because group calls do not have a chat associated with them. The ChatInfo property is only populated for one-on-one calls where a chat thread is created.
Please check this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/meeting-transcripts/fetch-id
